# How to print the sum of a passing a int array as a parameter

Tags: c, function, parameters, sum

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumofArrayNum(int numList[]);

int main(){
int result,numList[]={23,32,54,23,54,32,3,35};

result = sumofArrayNum(numList);
printf("sum= %d", result);
return 0;
}

int sumofArrayNum(int numList[]){
 int sum = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
   sum += numList[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Output is different each time I build and run it.
E.g. output is sum = 1032918821

Expected output I would like is sum = 256

Comment: How many elements are in the array?  How many elements are you counting?

Comment: Up to 10 elements inside the array. Is it that I have to enter 10 elements since I set the value to 10. Would input be better to solve this problem

Comment: You have 8 elements in your array, which means that the valid indices for looping would be 0 to 7. What is your loop when summing doing?

Comment: The loop should add all the elements together and return the final sum. It should iterate through the loop 10 times starting from index 0 and ending at 9 until the condition is met. Since its less than 10. It should print the sum of all 10 elements.

Comment: It can't iterate 10 times through an array that only has 8 elements. Where do you expect the non-existent elements to come from? There is no *all 10 elements* to sum when your array only contains 8. Think about it. If you write 8 numbers in a column on a piece of paper, how could you sum 10 numbers? You can't, because the 9th and 10th numbers don't exist. In programming, those extra two elements you're reading that don't exist are read from uninitialized stack memory, which means they're garbage, which is why you get a different total every time.

Comment: Thanks. Will be using Scanf then to solve the problem.

Comment: No. A better solution would be to modify your summing function to accept a second parameter, which would be the length of the array. You could then use that as the terminating condition for your loop, allowing you to pass any size array to the function.

Comment: If its not that much to ask can you show me your solution in code. I am beginner taking a crash course in c. I am very new to programming. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I've given you the information you need. Make an effort to implement it yourself - you'll learn much more that way than you will if I do it for you.

Comment: I will post my solution later today after implementing your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters like `int numList[]` is the same as `int* numList`, compiler will not know elements count of it if it was not **explicitly** defined. By the way, `int numList[8]` is also the same as `int* numList`. C language does **not** check the range of array.

There are some ways to get and check the array size.

- size/count parameter

```c
int sumofArrayNum(int numList[], int listSize){
 int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i){
   sum += numList[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Here `listSize` should be the **count** of elements.

And you can use macro to hide the count parameter:

```c
#define sumofArray(array) sumofArrayNum((array), sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array))
```

- point to the whole array

```c
int sumofArrayNum(int (*numList)[8]){
 int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(*numList)/sizeof(**numList); ++i){
   sum += (*numList)[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Call it by sending pointer of array:

```c
result = sumofArrayNum(&numList);
```

Compiler(such as gcc) can do a weak check for this: give a warning if you send an array which are not `int (*)[8]`.

Note that you have to ensure validity of array, and array size must be constant.

---

Besides,

> Output is different each time I build and run it.

It is because only 8 elements has been defined, index range is **0〜7**. `numList[8]` and `numList[9]` is undefined, mean any value is possible. Maybe used, changed by other process, random and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

In `numlist` there are 8 element that means for loop must execute code 8 times.
Your code must be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
   sum += numList[i];
}
```

This code iterate until `i=7`, when `i=8` it will end the loop.

Information on [`for loop`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm)